# Clean up for better performance in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL server,Sorry if is very basic question.
I am monitoring one table in which i am inserting data daily.I am using 
sp_spaceused SP to Monitoring .Below is the summary of space used in the table:

[image]

I want to clear data of this table for better performance.Now how i will come to know that how much data i can insert in table(is there any limit to insert data in table)? After how many day i should delete old data to get better performance? Is there any way i can fixed the storage size of table?

Your help is appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: What performance problems are you having?

Comment: @stuartd this is the one of the main table of my application so I want to be carefull with this table.

Comment: @sony921 What performance problems are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how i will come to know that how much data i can insert in table(is
>   there any limit to insert data in table)?

There is no limit.

> After how many day i should delete old data to get better performance?

It depends on your application. Usually you don't need to delete any "old data" at all.
I think, in your case, you either don't have proper index or SQL-Server doesn't use it for some reason. You have to look at execution plan first.

> Is there any way i can fixed the storage size of table?

1. Change datatype of columns where it is possible. For example, from `datetime` to `date`, from `int` to `tinyint`, from `char(50)` to `varchar(50)` and so on.
2. Aggregate and move history data to analitical tables.
3. Drop unused indexes.
4. Remove unused columnes from indexes.
5. Rebuild indexes if there is high fragmentation.

But, as I already said, your problem barely connected with the size of the table.

Comment: this is what i was looking for . Thanks you soo much

Comment: @sony921 Glad that helped you )